# Nintendo Switch Pro Controller acts as a mouse instead of a gamepad on PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, nintendo-switch, fortnite-battle-royale

I have switched from playing Fortnite on my Switch to PC. I have to use my controller wired because my PC doesn't support BlueTooth.

However, I've got a problem: when I use my controller, my PC reads my inputs as mouse inputs. For example if I move my joystick around, it moves the cursor. I have watched dozens of videos on YouTube but none of them helped and because I played with my Steam settings, the problem has gotten worse.

Does anybody know how to reset Steam settings or how I can solve my problem?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? In game, when you use your controller instead of a mouse you want it to act as your mouse, correct?

Comment: No, my problem is the exact opposite. I want the controller to act as a controller, not mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have Steam configured with a Desktop Configuration that binds the joystick to mouse movement. Connect your Switch Pro controller and open Steam, then go to Steam menu -> Settings, click "Controller", and click "Desktop Configuration". This should launch Steam Controller Configurator with the Desktop Configuration profile.

To unbind the joystick, find the rectangular region that shows a line pointing to the joystick when you hover over it. Click the region, a dialog should pop up. For "Style of Input", change it to "None". Click Back to close the dialog and then Done to exit the configurator tool.

Comment: This didn't help with Fortnite. It just disabled my controller on the desktop. If you've seen people playing with a gamepad on Fortnite PC, then you know that when they use their controller all of the UI turns to match controller. But for me, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try adding Fortnite to Steam as a Non-Steam Game. This lets you launch it from Steam with the Steam overlay active. The overlay also provides Steam's controller support, and if you've enabled "Switch Pro Configuration Support" in Steam's controller settings then it should let you use Switch Pro as if it were an XInput gamepad.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Xbox360 controller. The way I have solved it now is to disable Xbox configuration support. To be honest, I'm not yet sure what the side effects are, but at least for the games I play, it works.

Open Steam, go into the Steam menu > settings > controller > general controller settings.
And in your case, uncheck Switch pro config support.

For reference, this is where I found the solution: https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/133256959376939467/

Answer (score 0):

Bro all you need to do is go to steam<settings<in-game and enable the Steam Overlay while in-game, it worked for me finally ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was having very similar issues when trying to get my Nintendo Switch Pro controller connected. My main goal was to get it to work on Little Nightmares. The game by default has controller options configured for an Xbox 360/1 controller.

I discovered [this article](https://medium.com/everygeek/how-to-use-your-switch-pro-controller-to-play-any-pc-game-c49cd62b24a4) where I found a program that essentially emulates your Nintendo Switch Pro controller as an Xbox controller, thus allowing you to utilize those features.

The program that is used is called [BetterJoy/BetterJoyForCemu](https://github.com/Davidobot/BetterJoy).
This program was initially only meant for used with an emulator, however it now works for other PC games.

Hopefully this helps someone.